# Invalid Date issue for my date string

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have followed the tutorial : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/live-local-time-google-time-zone-api.shtml

And now I want to break it into two functions:

function #1. return the current time of a set timezone in milliseconds

function #2. increment the localdate object in function#1 by 1 second every second and insert it in the

But I get the output "Invalid Date"
Here is my code:

```js
var loc = '37.7749295, -122.4194155'; // San Francisco expressed as lat, lng tuple
 var targetDate = new Date(); // Current date/time of user computer
 var timestamp = targetDate.getTime() /1000 + targetDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60; // Current UTC date/time expressed as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC
 var apikey = 'Google_Time_Zone_key'; // timezone API key
 var apicall = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=' + loc +'&timestamp=' + timestamp + '&key=' + apikey;

function current_time_load1 () {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest (); // create new XMLHttpRequest2 object
 xhr.open ('GET', apicall); // open GET request
 xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status === 200) { // if Ajax request successful
      var output = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); // convert returned JSON string to JSON object
           // console.log(output.status); // log API return status for debugging purpose
         if (output.status =='OK') { // if API reports everthing was returned sucessfully
       var offsets = output.dstOffset * 1000 + output.rawOffset * 1000; // get DST and time zone offsets in milliseconds
       var localdate = new Date (timestamp * 1000 + offsets); // Date object containing current time of destination (timestamp + dstOffset + rawOffset)
             // localdate.toLocaleString(); // Display current destination date and time
            var refreshDate = new Date(); // get current date again to calculate time elapsed between targetDate and now
                var millisecondselapsed = refreshDate - targetDate; // get amount of time elapsed between targetDate and now
                localdate.setMilliseconds(localdate.getMilliseconds()+ millisecondselapsed); // update localdate to account for any time elapsed
            }
          }
   else { 
       console.log ('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
   } //end of xhr.onload
  }
 xhr.send(); // send request 
 }

function current_time_load(divid){
  var container = document.getElementById(divid);
  var localdate = new Date (current_time_load1 ());
  setInterval(function(){
                    localdate.setSeconds(localdate.getSeconds()+1);
                    container.innerHTML = localdate.toLocaleTimeString('zh', {year : 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'});
                }, 1000);
}
  
  current_time_load('time');
```

```html
<div>
test current time: <span id="time"></span>
</div>
```

I did check the value of current_time_load1() in console.log shows undefined, but the console.log(localdate.setMilliseconds(localdate.getMilliseconds()+ millisecondselapsed);) does return the milliseconds

Could you help to point out what's wrong with the split?

Answer (score 0):

Couple hours of searching around, I finally realized it needs a callback to retrieve the result of the XmlHttpRequest. Here is what works for me:

```js
function current_time_load1 (callback) {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest (); // create new XMLHttpRequest2 object
 xhr.open ('GET', apicall); // open GET request
 xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status === 200) { // if Ajax request successful
      var output = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); // convert returned JSON string to JSON object
           // console.log(output.status); // log API return status for debugging purpose
         if (output.status =='OK') { // if API reports everthing was returned sucessfully
       var offsets = output.dstOffset * 1000 + output.rawOffset * 1000; // get DST and time zone offsets in milliseconds
       var localdate = new Date (timestamp * 1000 + offsets); // Date object containing current time of destination (timestamp + dstOffset + rawOffset)
             // localdate.toLocaleString(); // Display current destination date and time
            var refreshDate = new Date(); // get current date again to calculate time elapsed between targetDate and now
                var millisecondselapsed = refreshDate - targetDate; // get amount of time elapsed between targetDate and now
                if(callback) { 
                    callback(localdate.setMilliseconds(localdate.getMilliseconds()+ millisecondselapsed));
                } // update localdate to account for any time elapsed
               //console.log(localdate.setMilliseconds(localdate.getMilliseconds()+ millisecondselapsed));
            }
          }
   else { 
       console.log ('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
   } //end of xhr.onload
  }
 xhr.send(); // send request 
 }

  current_time_load1(function (result){
    console.log('okay');
  var container = document.getElementById('test');
  var localdate = new Date(result);
  setInterval(function(){
                    localdate.setSeconds(localdate.getSeconds()+1);
                    container.innerHTML = localdate.toLocaleTimeString('zh', {year : 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'});
                }, 1000);
}, function(){
    console.log('fail');
  });
```

So, I basically added `if(callback){callback();}`to the current_time_load1 function. Then run this fuction with a new function that has the "result" parameter in it. A good lesson to learn :)